# Sencha Touch, setRecord() not working. Fields are blank.

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch...

I've been searching and asking people for hours, but cannot figure out why my detail view does not get the data (using setRecord).

I have not been able to find an example that uses Ext.NavigationView to push a view that uses the data from setRecord, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong there.

I have a tabbed view. First tab shows a list of items. Click an item disclosure to see details for that item. The detail view appears, but with no any data.

- The tabs are setup in the launch function of ViewPortController.
- The main view in the first tab is the PeopleListView. All the people appear in the list.
- The PeopleListView is added to an Ext.NavigationView. A reference to the Ext.NavigationView is added to the PeopleListView so it can be used later
- PeopleListViewController has a function, showDetailView, that is successfully called when a disclosure button is tapped.
- The controller's showDetailView function

  - sets the record (which contains the correct data) on the personDetailView,
  - retrieves the instance of the Ext.NavigationView and pushes the PersonDetailView.
- The record value passed to showDetailView has the correct data.
- When personDetailView appears, the fields have no data.

ViewPortController:

```
launch: function() {
    // var personDetailView = {
    //    xtype: 'persondetailview'
    // }
    var pplView = Ext.create('PeopleApp.view.PeopleListView');
    var pplNavView = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
        title: 'People',
        iconCls: 'home',
        useTitleForBackButtonText: true,
    });
    pplView.setNavigationView(pplNavView);
    pplNavView.add(pplView);
    . . .
    var mainViewPort = getMainViewPort();
    mainViewPort.setItems([pplNavView, . . .]);
},
```

PersonModel:

```
Ext.define('PeopleApp.model.PersonModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Rest'],
config: {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id',       type: 'auto'   },
        { name: 'name',     type: 'string' },
        { name: 'address',  type: 'string' },
        { name: 'email',    type: 'string' },
        { name: 'age',      type: 'int'    },
        { name: 'gender',   type: 'string' },
        { name: 'note',     type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/app/data/people.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'people'
        }
    },
}
});
```

PeopleListViewController:

```
Ext.define('PeopleApp.controller.PeopleListViewController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
xtype: 'peoplelistviewcontroller',
config: {
    refs: {
        peopleListView: 'peoplelistview',
        personDetailView: 'persondetailview',
        peopleView: 'peopleview',
    },
    control: {
        peopleListView: {
            discloseDetail: 'showDetailView'
        }
    }
},

showDetailView: function(view, record) {
    console.log("record.data.name=" + record.data.name);

    var detailView = Ext.create('PeopleApp.view.PersonDetailView');
    //var detailView = this.getPersonDetailView();
    detailView.setRecord(record);
    var navView = view.getNavigationView();
    navView.push(detailView);
},

launch: function() { this.callParent(arguments); },
init: function() { this.callParent(arguments); },
});
```

PersonDetailView:

```
Ext.define('PeopleApp.view.PersonDetailView', {
extend: 'PeopleApp.view.BaseView',
xtype: 'persondetailview',
requires: [
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.form.Text',
    'Ext.form.TextArea'
],
config: {
    title: "Person Details",
    scrollable: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'name',
                label: 'Name: ',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'age',
                label: 'Age: ',
                required: false
            }, // etc.
        ]}
    ]}
});
```

Can you tell me why detailView.setRecord(record) does not get the data set in the fields of DetailViewController, and what I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you should use below code in your Person detail view:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype:'formpanel',
        id:'personDetailViewForm',
        items:[{
                 xtype: 'fieldset',
                 items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Name: ',
                    required: true
                  }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'age',
                    label: 'Age: ',
                    required: false
                  }, // etc.
                ]
             }]
       }]
```

and in the personListViewController you can set that form's values instead of setting records to the view like:

```
   var detailView = Ext.create('PeopleApp.view.PersonDetailView');
   var personDetailViewForm = detailView.down('#personDetailViewForm ');
   personDetailViewForm .setValues(records);
```

Note that records object property names and form fields names must match and if `records` doesn't work try with `records.data`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Wow, items arrays nested 3 levels deep. I haven't seen the .down function. I gave this a try. My personDetailView comes up blank now. Not even the fields or labels appear.

Comment: Answer: Your suggestion had xtype: 'formpanel' which was on the right path. The PersonDetailView extends PeopleApp.view.BaseView, which in turns extends Ext.Container. When I changed to extend 'Ext.form.Panel' (not Ext.Panel which I had also tried) all worked well. Thanks!